Concern Regarding Discrepancy in Parents' Last Names on Passport for US Visa Application
If my parents' last names in my passport differ from their actual passports, could this potentially cause any issues during their US visa application process?

Ho much different? Just spelling? Is it expected or frequent in your home country (to have such differences)?

Is there a difference because of the names actually being in a different script and differently transcriped?
